# Replace sys_extract_utc in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I'm using the following query in Oracle, I need the same in MySQL also.

```
select sys_extract_utc(systimestamp) into currGMTDate from dual;
```

I tried with `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` instead of `systimestamp`

but the output that I got was a different one. How can I get the same result in MySQL for the above Oracle query?

Comment: _"but the output that I got was a different one."_ Could you edit you question to show both outputs (Oracle vs MySQL) side by side ?

Comment: So you are just wanting to get current system time in UTC in MySQL? Have you tried `UTC_TIMESTAMP`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with the below query and it worked for me

```
select date_format(CONVERT_TZ( current_timestamp, @@session.time_zone, '+00:00' ),'%d-%m-%Y %r')
```